# Warning when upgrading Fluent 1.2 from NH 3.0 to 3.1 -- ProxyFactoryFactory is obsolete, moved to

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I'm fairly new to NHibernate and Fluent NHibernate and I've been using Fluent 1.2 for NH 3.0 for about 6 months.  I just upgraded to Fluent 1.2 for NH 3.1.  Now I'm getting a warning (in Visual Studio), and I've tried to fix it but no luck.  I could use some help...

In my Global.asax file, I Fluently-configure NHibernate:

```
var nhConfig = Fluently.Configure()
.Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(connstr =>     connstr.FromConnectionStringWithKey("MyDatabase"))                
.ProxyFactoryFactory<ProxyFactoryFactory>().AdoNetBatchSize(100))
.Mappings(mappings => mappings.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MyClass>())
.ExposeConfiguration(c => c.Properties.Add("current_session_context_class", "web"))
.BuildConfiguration();
```

I'm getting a warning on the line:

```
.ProxyFactoryFactory<ProxyFactoryFactory>().AdoNetBatchSize(100))
```

Here's the warning:

```
FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.PersistenceConfiguration<FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration,
FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConnectionStringBuilder>.ProxyFactoryFactory<TProxyFactoryFactor  y>()'
 is obsolete: 'Moved to FluentConfiguration  Fluently.Configure().ProxyFactoryFactory(...))'
```

I think I need to use the FluentlyConfigure().ProxyFactoryFactory(), but the help/intellisense for that method says it's only for NH 2.1.

What should I be doing in my configuration to eliminate this warning and not use obsolete/deprecated methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the last couple of FluentNHibernate builds, the `ProxyFactoryFactory` method was moved out of `Database` to directly off of `Configure`.  Try this:

```
var nhConfig = Fluently.Configure()
.ProxyFactoryFactory<ProxyFactoryFactory>()
.Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("MyDatabase").AdoNetBatchSize(100))
.Mappings(mappings => mappings.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MyClass>())
.ExposeConfiguration(c => c.Properties.Add("current_session_context_class", "web"))
.BuildConfiguration();
```

Comment: Have you seen any resources for working with sybase?  The issue I have is that I have to connect to three different databases... The code below is what we are using and I am having a very difficult time changing this out ...
  return new SybaseConfiguration()
                .Dialect<SybaseASA9Dialect>()
                .ProxyFactoryFactory<ProxyFactoryFactory>()
                .Driver<DataDirectSybaseDriver>()
                .Provider<JCDCConnectionProvider>()
                .ConnectionString(container)
                .ShowSql();